# EF6 Foreign Key Conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

This is the content of my DivorceCases.cs file inside Models:

```
public class DivorceCases
{
    public string case_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Transactions t { get; set; }
}
public class DivorceCasesContext : DbContext
{
    public DivorceCasesContext() : base("mssqlDB") { }
    public DbSet<DivorceCases> DivorceCase { get; set; }
}
```

This is the content of my CorporationCases.cs file inside Models:

```
public class CorporationCases
{
    public string case_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Transactions t { get; set; }
}
public class CorporationCasesContext : DbContext
{
    public CorporationCasesContext() : base("mssqlDB") { }
    public DbSet<CorporationCases> CorporationCase { get; set; }
}
```

Now my question is:

I am using code-first approach to let EF6 create table for me automatically.

when I try to create and use any instance of table and EF6 creates it as well for `DivorceCases Model` and Context pair. But after the `DivorceCases` table has been created, I try to create and use `CorporationCases` Model instance then EF6 fails to automatically create the table for me because

> "Transaction" Table has already been created by DivorceCases context

So how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create 2 `dbContext` here.just use one as shown below.

**Important Note :** You're not following basic naming conventions.I highly recommend to use those.

one place is here : `public DbSet<DivorceCases> DivorceCase { get; set; }`

need to be corrected as `public DbSet<DivorceCase> DivorceCases { get; set; }`

**Using One DbContext :**

```
public class DivorceCases
{
    public string case_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Transactions t { get; set; }
}

public class CorporationCases
{
    public string case_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Transactions t { get; set; }
}

public class YourCasesContext : DbContext
{
    public YourCasesContext () : base("mssqlDB") { }

    public DbSet<DivorceCases> DivorceCase { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CorporationCases> CorporationCase { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it like I had been doing it wrong all time and just one DbContext is enough for the entire project with several tables?

Comment: yes,no problem at all.You can handle any number of tables by using 1 `dbContext`.

Comment: oh thanks a lot. Your solution works like a charm. You really saved my day.